Difference between connect and connect_robust in aio-pika
I'm working with aio-pika to interact with RabbitMQ asynchronously in Python. While exploring the library, I came across two methods for establishing a connection:

aio_pika.connect()
aio_pika.connect_robust()

I understand that both are used to connect to RabbitMQ, but I'm unsure about their differences. Also, I am curious that what are the differences between objects that have Robust prefix with other objects in the aio-pika.
I'm looking for clarification on their purpose, use cases, and how they differ when handling connection interruptions, retries, or failure scenarios.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
